# Mantener efecto hover al seleccionar

Tags: html5, css3

Necesito que cuando seleccione una opción esta quede seleccionada del mismo color 
 que está el hover, que es el color  `#F5B90E`. Este menú es desplegable osea que cuando elija las etiquetas, estas se queden con el color del hover al darle click, en este momento solo funciona pasando el mouse

**código  html**

```
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseCaracterizacion" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseCaracterizacion">
            <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
            <span>Seguriad</span>
        </a>
        <div id="collapseCaracterizacion" class="collapse m-0" aria-labelledby="headingCaracterización" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
            <div class="bg-light-black py-2 collapse-inner">
                <a   class="collapse-item image" [routerLink]="['/']">Audirorías </a>
                <a class="collapse-item" [routerLink]="['/rol']">Roles</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

**código CSS**

```
.sidebar .nav-item .collapse .collapse-inner .collapse-item:hover,
.sidebar .nav-item .collapsing .collapse-inner .collapse-item:hover {
  color: #7B3A24;
  background-color: #F5B90E;
}


.sidebar .nav-item .collapse .collapse-inner .collapse-item:active,
.sidebar .nav-item .collapsing .collapse-inner .collapse-item:active {
  background-color: #F5B90E;
}

.sidebar .nav-item .collapse .collapse-inner .collapse-item.active,
.sidebar .nav-item .collapsing .collapse-inner .collapse-item.active {
  color: #7B3A24;
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: #F5B90E;
}
```

Comment: Lo que se me ocurre es que captures el evento con Jquery e insertes la clase cuando el puntero este sobre esa etiqueta en particular.

Comment: No Jquery, solo html, css

Comment: @Hackerman, imposible lo que pides, debes de considerar utilizar javascript, jquery u otra libreria de tu gusto